# Android, get item view at a position in the list

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to flash an item at a position in the list view based on the user's action, but having trouble of getting the correct view.

I'm using an extended CursorAdapter for my list, so the getView function looks like below.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LogUtils.LOGD("GETVIEW CALLED", mGetView+"");
    LogUtils.LOGD("position ", position+"");
    mGetView++;
    if (!mDataValid) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
    }
    if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
    }
    Model model = QueryHelper.getModelFromCursor(mCursor);
    View v;
    if (convertView == null) {
        v = newView(mContext, model, parent);
    } else {
        v = convertView;
    }
    bindView(v, mContext, model);
    long id = model.getId();
    idToViewMap.put(id,v);
    idToPositionMap.put(id,mCursor.getPosition());
    return v;
}
```

In the following function, the View returned is wrong, it's 3 items below the correct position. I guess it's got something to do with the convert view, but I'm not sure. Any idea? Thanks.

```
 public void flashItemDelay(Context context, String sId){
    Toast.makeText(context, sId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    final Long id = Long.parseLong(sId);



    int pos = mAdapter.getPositionByItemId(id);//correct position
    mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(pos); //works well


    Handler transitionHandler = new Handler();
    transitionHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            View view = mAdapter.getViewByItemId(id);//WRONG view
            TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) view.getBackground();
            transition.startTransition(500);
            transition.reverseTransition(500);
        }
    }, 200);

}
```

Comment: why don't you do ..             View view = mAdapter.getViewByItemId(id + 3);

Comment: @AhmedEkri why is that '3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ListViews`, the idea is to make changes on the underlying data and let the adapter reflect the changes on the views. You shouldn't try to find the view, instead you should make the changes on data model and handle it on the adapter to reflect the result on the view.

For example, you can add a boolean flag `shouldFlash` to your Model class and in your adapter data you can set it on the item which you want to flash. In the `getView()` method, you can check it and flash the view(in your case, you should also reset the `shouldFlash` flag immediately.).

The key here is to inform the view that the underlying data has been refreshed. In `ArrayAdapter`, this is `notifyDataSetChanged()` method while the corresponding for the `CursorAdapter` is `changeCursor()` or `swapCursor()`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the thing is that the 'shouldFlash' information comes in after the view is created. What I'm trying to build is something like Facebook notification. You get a system notification (say, for a new comment that tagged you) outside the app, but if you click on it, it will open the app, render the list of comments, and flash that particular comment.

Comment: What you want perfectly matches with the paradigm I described above. An information outside of the app comes(it is an update on the model), you make this change on the data and then refresh the adapter.

Comment: Tim, after checking, I followed your way and did solve the problem, thanks.